# Delay a command while showing a toast

Tags: android

In my App, I want to display random numbers and I have a delay between them of 3 seconds. While the command has being delayed, I want to show a toast.

```
public void random(View v)
{
    Toast myToast = Toast.makeText(this, "Wait...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    myToast.show();

try{
    Thread.sleep(3000);
}
catch (InterruptedException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}

int number= random.nextInt(6) + 1;

// ...
```

I tried this code but it delays first and then shows the Toast. I want the Toast to be shown between the numbers. 
Can anyone help me, please?

Thanks, Marco

Comment: It shows the toast after the delay because you're sleeping the UI thread.

Comment: You should use a handler rather than doing it on the main thread. Thats why you getting this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out:

This will get random number every 3 seconds and show a Toast.

```
Handler handler=new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
        public void run() {
          int number= random.nextInt(6) + 1;
          .......
         Toast myToast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wait...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
         myToast.show();          
      }}, 3000);
```

Comment: Oh..my bad..i will just edit my answer. It should not be this in makeText

Comment: Just updated the answer, in the `makeText()`, the first parameter should/can be either `YourActivityname.this` or `getApplicationContext()`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to set your UI thread sleeping.
There is the concept of Timer and TimerTask for such purposes.

```
    private void testTimer(){
    TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //random number generation;
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(YourActivityOrContext.this, "Wait...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
        }
    };
    Timer t = new Timer();
    t.schedule(task, 3000);
}
```

It's not "better" than Ranjith's solution, just another.
Actually Timer and TimerTask are Java, while Handler is Android.
But runOnUiThread, which you need to use because only the UI Thread has 
access to it's views, will use the Handler, too.